# R `t.test` problem cause `159 equal to 8875`

Tags: r

R version is 3.5.3 (2019-03-11),have a look of below output:

```
> t.test(a$score,a$time,paired=FALSE)

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  a$score and a$time
t = -1.4861, df = 8382, p-value = 0.1373
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -20215.279   2781.535
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 159.0481 8875.9203
```

`p value` is 0.1373(>0.05),but the mean of 2 variables are `159.0481` and `8875.9203`.

I upload `.Rdata` to https://file.io/EH9XV44u

Anything wrong with my `t.test`?

Comment: Because your data is spread out enough that the difference in means is statistically not significant.

Comment: Also, why exactly are you comparing "score" to "time"? That doesn't seem to make any sense

Comment: @HongOoi,no reason `159.0481 vs 8875.9203` is `statistically not significant`.

Comment: item name like `score`,`time` are not involved into `t.test`

Comment: The data are probably highly skewed, and most likely have large standard deviations, or both. And probably the sample size is small. Perhaps the t-test is not appropriate here

Comment: Can you upload an RDS file instead of the r data file? I can see if I cen help you with your analysis.

Comment: Can anyone help to move this question to `cross validated`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the title of your question shows the problem here.

The result that a mean of 159 in one set of data does not demonstrate a significant difference to a mean of 8875 in another set of data doesn't mean '159 equal to 8875'.

It just means that the data allow sufficient uncertainty about the 'true' values of the means (from which the data were picked) that you can't say with confidence that they are different.

Even though - intuitively - you might think that 159 'looks' very different to 8875, we perform a statistical test to verify (or refute) our intuition that this difference couldn't have arisen by chance.  In this case, it seems that intuition is wrong.

As Edward & Hong Oui have said in the comments, this is probably because one (or both) of your datasets are very dispersed, so the mean alone doesn't reflect the amount of uncertainty.

An extreme example, which might make this clearer:

`data1: c(7,105,365)` = mean 149

`data2: c(3,22,26600)` = mean 8875

It's clear (to me) that we can't be very confident that data1 and data2 are really different, since the difference in the mean value arises from just a single high value in data2.  So, although the means seem very different, we don't expect that this will be significant if we test it.

Indeed:

```
t.test(data1,data2)
# p-value = 0.4291
```

I guess that if you look closely at your own data you'll find something similar...